# Why getAsyncKeyState() doesn't work well in cmd with quick edit mode

Tags: c, cmd, mouseevent

```
int GetMouseClicked()//if mouse_L_button is clicked -> return 1;
{
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) < 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When using `GetAsyncKeyState()` to input mouse left button, in test, my cmd change to Select mode after clicked mouse left button. And this doesn't print out message I called by `printf()` or `puts()` until I press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or <kbd>ESC</kbd>. But after turn off quick edit mode, It print out message after clicked.

Why doesn't work in quick edit mode when I use `GetAsyncKeyState()`?

Comment: pardon me, but is it in `c`?

Comment: This is a feature of the console window of course, not a bug.  Imagine how hard it would be to select text on a constantly scrolling console.  Your program still updates the console screen buffer, you just can't see it.  You can turn the text select feature off, use GetConsoleMode() and SetConsoleMode, turning off the ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE option.

Comment: Thanks so much, Hans Passant.
I know that GetAsyncKeyState() is in C API and I use in C source in VS, Sourav Ghosh.